# Android: Ping server in every 10 minutes

Tags: android, service, garbage-collection, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I need to ping server(api call) in every 10 mins, api call should be working if my application runs in background. Please suggest me the better option.

Right now I used Service, but it get finish after some time if my application is in background(due to GC clear).

How to avoid GC clear if application runs in background. Please help me.

Comment: I already created service. but it stop after some time, due to GC clear.

Comment: Use START_STICKY in your service, your service will automatically get restarted as soon as resources are available

Comment: @kapil thadani How to call service in every 10 mins (by using AlarmManager/TimerTask/Timer/Handler/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart your service automatically after being killed, set the service sticky.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for that. A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.
There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

**Example :**

```
private final static int TIMEINTERVAL = 600000; //10 minutes
Handler mHandler;
Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
 {
 @Override 
 public void run() {
      // call your api here.    
         ApiCall();
         mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, TIMEINTERVAL);
 }
};

private void startTask(){
   //run your Task 
     mHandlerTask.run(); 
}

private void stopTask()
{
  // stop your Task
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
}
```

You can also use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and set a repeating alarm from your Activity which will invoke the receiver every 10 minutes:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),600000,
                                                                  pendingIntent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {   
  //Call your API
 }

 }
```

**Registerd Receiver in your Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
android:name="com.YourPackage.AlarmReceiver"
android:exported="false">
```